# How to include text file into javascript

Tags: javascript, import, include, inline

Is there any way to load some text from another file into javascript, without server side code?

I was thinking to use another  element to hold the text inside some comments, but I don't know how to read it's source code with javascript.

Something like:

`<script src="myfile.js"></script>`

`<script> function readMyText() { ... }</script>`

In myfile.js:
`/* some text */`

Comment: Load text and do what with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using ajax or any server code... sorry mate but you can't :(

Answer (score 12):

You can put anything you want into a script tag if you give it a "type" that's not something the browser understands as meaning "JavaScript":

```
<script id='Turtle' type='text/poem'>
  Turtle, turtle, on the ground;
  Pink and shiny - turn around.
</script>
```

You can get the contents via the "innerHTML" property:

```
var poemScript = document.getElementById('Turtle');
var poem = poemScript.innerHTML;
```

[Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/HmJZA/)

That trick is popular lately with people doing client-side page building via templates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this works nicely when the text is added within the script tag, but if i change this to `<script href="turtle.txt"></script>` I can't access the contents :( . I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah yes, that's true.  Well, you could try pulling the script into a hidden `<iframe>` and then read it out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Pointy's answer, to import from local files do this:

```
<script src="foo.txt" id="text" type="text">
</script>
```

You could also use this to target an external file:

```
<script src="http://foo.txt"></script>
```