# How to read and write from a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

There are many similar questions to this, however, when I used the code provided, it didn't work. My code is as follows:

```
  function write(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('archive.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
      // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
          console.log('Write completed.');
        };
        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
          console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
        };
        var blob = new Blob([prompt("MESSAGE: ")], {type: 'text/plain'});
        fileWrite.write(blob);
      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
  }
  function onInitFs(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('archive.txt', {}, function(fileEntry) {
      // Get a File object representing the file,
      // then use FileReader to read its contents.
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onloadend = function(e) {
           var txtArea = document.createElement('textarea');
           txtArea.value = this.result;
           document.body.appendChild(txtArea);
         };
         reader.readAsText(file);
      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
  }
  window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

The file `archive.txt` does exist but when I call the function, it doesn't work. So instead I used window.requestFileSystem() which I found on a website. However, when I compile this code through Github, it doesn't work.

Also, if someone could tell me a way to read and write to a file without using php as this is all in html file using Github without git. I have another file in Github in the same directory as this. Would I need to include the full directory rather than archive.txt?

Comment: Maybe you should be clear whehter the javascripts are executed in server (using nodejs, something similar to php because they are not static) or in client (browser). If in browser, you are not reading a file but requesting a file from the server (through url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible without server side code.

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433250/how-to-include-text-file-into-javascript) a while ago.